# Easy way to integrate local or SMB files

Tags: notion-api, notion

this is not exactly related to the API as it doesn't allow such complex integrations, at least for now. Even so, if someone has found a solution to integrate this in some way I would love to know and share it.

I have been missing a feature for a long time. The possibility to put a link to a file from the local computer or from a SMB/WebDav directory...

As you know, Notion is not good for file persistence and I think most of us still prefer disk storage. Integrations with Drive and OneDriven have been offered, but not iCloud Drive for example. But I as a person who appreciates the privacy of my files would like to be able to reference a file from my premises.
So far I have been doing it by sharing a link to icloud drive and pasting it in a block, but I want to start moving my data to a private cloud and this solution never convinced me as it is tedious.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to incorporate this functionality?